# Using pointers as array, returning references

Tags: c++

```
const char* occurs(const char* s1, const char* st){
  if(length(st)>length(s1)){
    return 0;
  }

  int diff=length(s1)-length(st);
  int i=0, j=0, k=0;

  for(;i<=diff;i++){
    j=i;

    while(s1[j]==st[k] && st[k]!='\0'){
      k++;
      j++;
    }

    if(st[k]=='\0') return &s1[i];
  }
    return 0;
}
```

This function returns the first occurrence of a string in another string. In my main function, I call it like this:

```
const char* occ = occurs(argv[1], argv[2]);
std::cout << &occ << " - " << occ << std::endl;
```

What confuses me is: being occ a pointer, shouldn't I get the address by writing the variable as is (occ) and the value by dereferencing it (*occ)? 
Why does it seem to be working like a normal variable (Getting the address with &occ and the value with occ)?
Does C++ change something about a pointer if I treat it like an array? If I solved the problem by considering s1 and st as pointers, without using the array semantic, would it have been the same in regards to the memory?

Comment: The output operator `<<` has a special overload for `const char*` to print a c-style string.

Comment: calling `length` again and again is not a good idea. Better use `str::string`

Comment: I see, didn't know about `<<`. 
Also, I know it's not a good idea, it's just an exercise to understand better pointers/arrays (so not using `str::string`) and I didn't bother saving the lengths in different variables, ahah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget that C-style strings (null-terminated byte strings as they are really called) are handled by a special overload of the `<<` operator to print the string itself.

What you print with `&occ` is the address of the `occ` variable itself, not where it points.

If you want to print the value contained inside the `occ` variable (i.e. where it points) then you need to cast it to a pointer-type which isn't handled specially like strings. Like e.g. `static_cast<const void*>(occ)`.

Comment: So, &occ is the address of the cell where the pointer to the C-style string is stored? If occ wasn't a C-style string, but a pointer to an array (or a pointer to something) I would've had to write `std::cout << occ << " - " << *occ << std::endl;` to actually see `address - value`, is that correct?

Comment: @Dodicin A string is really nothing more than an array of characters, with a special character terminating it. So as long as you don't have a string (if e.g. `occ` was an `int*`) then yes that's correct. Also remember that if `occ` points to the first element of an array then `*occ` will give you the value of that first element, it's equal to `occ[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, c++ did change something.
you have set the return type of function "occur" to const char* so this basically returns the pointer to the address of a variable.
But in your program you have returned a const r-value "0", what c++ did is that it didn't saw this as an r-value (which would lead to an error for values other than 0) it saw it as if it were a null pointer, that's why it didn't gave an error either.
so when you did this:-

const char* occ = occurs(argv[1], argv[2]);
"occ" was pointing to an invalid address and that's why didn't work as you would expected it to.

anyway, this was my explanation , feel free to confirm it as it may not answer your question precisely.

Comment: I don't think that's it! I know 0 is considered as a null pointer, but the `<<` override explains the unexpected behaviour I wasn't understanding better.